# Documentation/Code old Mishoo's Calendar javascript inline

Tags: javascript, calendar, magento-1.9

Working on some old javascript calendar, it behaves as a trigger->popup, I want it to be an inline calendar.

The only documentation I can find is [this one, but does not seem to match my version](http://calculateday.com/calendar/Manual.htm)

I have to work with it, because it is the way Magento 1.x shows a product's custom option calendar.

je calendar.js header:

```
/*  Copyright Mihai Bazon, 2002-2005 | www.bazon.net/mishoo
 * -----------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The DHTML Calendar, version 1.0 "It is happening again"
 *
 * Details and latest version at:
 * www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar
 *
 * This script is developed by Dynarch.com.  Visit us at www.dynarch.com.
 *
 * This script is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License.
 * Read the entire license text here: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html
 */
  // $Id: calendar.js,v 1.51 2005/03/07 16:44:31 mishoo Exp $
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated (documentation, code snippet, alternative lib...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [the answer](http://www.bernstein.oeaw.ac.at/twiki/pub/TWiki/JSCalendarContrib/doc/html/reference.html#node_sec_3.2); instead of "inline" calendar, that documentation deals of  "flat" calendar.
In my case, an ugly but fast way to do is in :

app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Date.php

- replace the content of calendarSetupObject and add the HTML container above.
- implement dateChanged so it updates the input:text, only on days of week (etc.)